# How can I join a c# code with a html text

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, razor, formatting

I'm trying to do this:

```
<h1> Pagina n@Model.Restaurant.Id</h1>
```

But, when I start the page the text is this:

```
Pagina n@Model.Restaurant.Id
```

How can I join the variable Model.Restaurant.Id with a text? Like this:

Model.Restaurant.Id = 5

```
Pagina n5
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you try concatenation?

Comment: <h1> Pagina n(@Model.Restaurant.Id)</h1>      https://dotnetfiddle.net/WXMpqd

Answer (score 2):

You can use string interpolation.

```
<h1>@($"Pagina n{Model.Restaurant.Id}")</h1>
```

Comment: And since the string in actual code naturally comes from resources there is really no other way to look for.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: 
`<h1> Pagina n<%= Model.Restaurant.Id %></h1>`
 or 
`<h1> Pagina n<%: Model.Restaurant.Id %></h1>`
 or 
`<h1> Pagina n@(Model.Restaurant.Id) %></h1>`